# Underscore to camelCase

Tags: sed

How can I convert underscore separated words to "camelCase"? Here is what I'm trying:

```
echo "remote_available_packages" | sed -r 's/([a-z]+)_([a-z])([a-z]+)/\1\U\2\L\3/'
```

But it returns `remoteAvailable_packages` without changing the `p` in `packages`.

Comment: needs more `/g` "global" on the sub

Comment: You are capturing everything on the left side of the `s` command leaving nothing to "repeat". Try `echo "remote_available_packages" | sed -r 's/([a-z]+)_([a-z])/\1\U\2/g'`

Comment: What do you want to get from input ``101_dalmations``?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This does that (in GNU sed):

```
echo "remote_available_packages" | sed -E 's/_(.)/\U\1/g'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't do perl...

Comment: You should use `-E` rather than `-r` with sed.  It's the POSIX standard option for enabling extended regular expressions in `sed`.   The `-r` option was used by some versions of `sed` to do the same thing and now exists only for legacy compatibility reasons.  `-E` is the correct, portable form that will work with all modernish versions of `sed`.  `-E` is also used for the same purpose by `grep` and other programs.

Comment: Note that on macOS, GNU sed is **not** the one in /usr/bin/sed

Answer (score 2):

In awk

```
echo 'remote_available_packages'  | awk -F _ '{printf "%s", $1; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s", toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2); print"";}'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
echo "remote_available_packages" | perl -pe 's/(^|_)([a-z])/uc($2)/ge'
```

Or:

```
echo "remote_available_packages" | perl -pe 's/_([a-z])/uc($1)/ge'
```

if the first letter should not be capitalized.